# C to OCaml - If conditions inside a for loop OCaml

Tags: c, ocaml

I'm trying to rewrite a C code into OCaml. However, I'm not sure how to work with multiple if conditions inside a for loop in OCaml. Can you help me figure out how to do that?
I have the C code and what I've done in OCaml, which isn't working.

C code:

```
bool function1 (int x, int y, int movei, int sol[][], int xMove[], int yMove[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, next_x, next_y; 
    if (movei == n) 
        return true; 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        next_x = x + xMove[i]; 
        next_y = y + yMove[i]; 

        if (function2(next_x, next_y, sol)) { 
            sol[next_x][next_y] = movei; 

            if (function1(next_x, next_y, movei + 1, sol, xMove, yMove, n)) 
                return true; 
            else
                sol[next_x][next_y] = 0;
        } 
    } 

    return false; 
}
```

---

**EDIT:** OCaml code

I've changed my OCaml code based on glennsl answer, but the compiler complains about '(' and ')' being unmatched and expected.

```
let rec function1 x y movei sol xMove yMove n =
if movei=n then true
else
    (
    for i=0 to n-1 do 
    (
        let next_x = x + xMove.(i) in
        let next_y = y + yMove.(i) in

            if (function2 next_x next_y sol) then 
            sol.(next_x).(next_y)<-movei in 
                (
                    if (function1 next_x next_y movei+1 sol xMove yMove n) then true
                    else sol.(next_x).(next_y)<-0
                )   
            else false  

    done;; )
)
```

Previous OCaml code:

```
let rec function1 x y movei sol xMove yMove n =
if movei=n then true
else
    for i=0 to n-1 do
        let next_x = x + xMove.(i);
        let next_y = y + yMove.(i);

            if (function2 next_x next_y sol) then
                sol.(next_x).(next_y)<-movei;

                    if (function1 next_x next_y movei+1 sol xMove yMove n) then true
                    else sol.(next_x).(next_y)<-0

            else ()

    done;;
```

The compiler says "Syntax error" in the last line of the OCaml code, where the *done;;* is.

Comment: Don't *rewrite your code* but *redesign your software* for and in Ocaml. You should change your programming style to be more functional. An Ocaml code mimicking a C code will be unreadable and is likely to have poor performance.

Comment: I'm quite new to OCaml, therefore it's kind of hard for me to do it at the moment. That is why I'm asking for help on this, as I don't know how to do this kind of "simple" stuff in C in OCaml.

Comment: But don't take the bad habit of rewriting C code in Ocaml. This will simply make learning Ocaml more difficult

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's been answered. SO is intended as a knowledge base of well-defined questions and answers, not a personal help desk. Also try to understand why you need to add parentheses, what an expression is, and what `;;` is and why you need it. Scattering parentheses around everywhere isn't a good solution short-term or long-term. And finally, you're chewing over way too much, probably because you're trying to literally translate C code as a whole without understanding its pieces.

Comment: The way you should go about it is: 1. Understand what the C code does, in high-level terms (i.e. it manipulates a certain data structure in a certain way, etc.). 2. Implement it in OCaml using this high-level description. The details of how it was done in C are not very relevant.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The syntax error you're getting is caused by the first `else` being interpreted as belonging to the first `if`, leaving the second `else` dangling. OCaml is not indentation sensitive, so you need to surround nested control structures with parentheses or `begin` and `end`, which are exactly the same as parentheses but look better when delimiting blocks of code. It's a good idea to use `ocp-indent` to automatically indent your code the way it'll be interpreted, which has the nice side-effect of revealing errors like this.
2. `let x = y` is a top-level declaration only and semicolon is not a statement terminator but an operator that chains expressions and throws away the result of the first. OCaml is an expression-based language, and while it does support imperative programming it does not have statements. What you want to use instead is `let x = y in z`, which binds the result of evaluating `y` to the name `x` in the expression `z`. Just replace the semicolons after the `let`s with `in`, then it'll work.
3. The branches of your `if`-expressions return different values. Most return `unit`, but two of them return a `bool`, which is a type error since the function, or any other expression, can't return both `unit` and `bool`. From the C code it looks like you should return `false` wherever you're now returning `()`, implicitly (if the expression evaluates to `()`) or explicitly.
4. OCaml also does not use whitespace for grouping, and so `function1 next_x next_y movei+1 sol xMove yMove n` will not be interpreted as you expect, but rather as `(function1 next_x next_y movei) + (1 sol xMove yMove n)` due to the precedence of function application being higher than that of the `+` operator. Surround `move+1` in parentheses to make it a single argument to `function1`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this example is the "return true;" that aborts the for loop and the whole recursion actually.

One way to mirror that kind of flow in imperative code in ocaml is to use an exception. So all `return true;` would become `raise Found`. The `return false;` is simply removed and the function returns a unit value.

You then add a second function that does

```
let function1 x y movei sol xMove yMove n =
    try
        function1 x y movei sol xMove yMove n;
        false
    with Found -> true
```

to restore the original API.